# Wrap a long word when resizing button

Tags: css

Right now I have following html code for subscribe button

```css
#submit {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" style="line-height: 1.35em; overflow-wrap: break-word;" />
```

When I create mobile phone layout, I meet following problem: When subscribe button resizes due to resizing of browser, instead of showing "subscribe", it becomes "subscr" or something shorter than the original word.

How can I wrap words inside button?

Comment: use media queries and adjust the font-size

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS.

```
.truncate {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`word-break: break-all` is I think what you're looking for if you want to wrap break by letter. There is also break-word if you prefer to do it per word.

```css
#submit {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" style="line-height: 1.35em; overflow-wrap: break-word;">Subscribewithlotsoftext</button>
```